# Magento 2 create Order programatically and set a custom date to it

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

I have a order to create an order in magento 2. But the order it create is with the date when i run the script. I don't want to save the current date for the order. I want to set a certain date to the that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky wat, you set your desired time to  created_at field

Magento 2 has a method **setCreatedAt()**   and using this method can set Order created time.

*So add below code after the end of your order creation code and run  `update()` of this code.*

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResourceModel
) {
    $this->orderResourceModel = $orderResourceModel;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function update()
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get(1); // 1 is  order id
    $order->setCreatedAt($createdAt); // set time
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);   

}
```

Comment: No it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.

My question was not fully complete. Sorry about that. I wanted the order date to be on certain date. The order is not yet created. I am creating the order using my custom code. To create an order i need to create Quote. So if i change the quote create and update date then i reflects to order date too.